# @MediaQuery Call In CSS

Tags: html, css, wordpress, stylesheet, media-queries

I have been adapting a site to make this more responsive, and i have been following the code from a demo which was sent to me.

However for some reason it doesnt appear to be resizing as stated in a mobile browser.

Im thinking its down to the fact that Wordpress calls style sheets slightly differently, do i need some form of plugin to do this?

Please see below header of my document referencing the other stylesheet but its not appearing to call it when browser is different (however it is effectively resizing in different resolutions)

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title><?php bloginfo('name'); ?> <?php if ( is_single() ) { ?> &raquo; Blog Archive <?php } ?> <?php wp_title(); ?></title>
<meta name="keywords" content="Holiday, free CSS template, clean, neat, aqua, white, templatemo" />
<meta name="description" content="Holiday is a clean and neat free CSS template using aqua and white colors." />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url'); ?>" type="text/css" />
<!-- Include jQuery -->
<?php wp_enqueue_script('jquery'); ?>
<?php wp_head(); ?>
<!-- Include the Nivo Slider CSS file -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo("template_url"); >/scripts/nivoslider/nivo-slider.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<!-- Include the Nivo Slider JS file -->
<script src="<?php bloginfo("template_url"); ?>/scripts/nivoslider/jquery.nivo.slider.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- Set up the Nivo Slider -->
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(window).load(function() {
jQuery('#slider').nivoSlider();
});
</script>
<!-- media queries css -->
<link href="media-queries.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<!-- html5.js for IE less than 9 -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->

<!-- css3-mediaqueries.js for IE less than 9 -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="http://css3-mediaqueries-js.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/css3-mediaqueries.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
</head>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you certain the path to your `media-queries.css` is right?  First ensure that the CSS is being loaded and then we can begin to discuss the actual media queries themselves.

If your file is in the **themes** folder then it would be something like:

```
/wp-content/themes/media-queries.css
```

Or:

```
<link href="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/media-queries.css" 
    rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
```

Comment: Or use an absolute URL to a path you know is valid i.e. <link href="//mysite.com/css/media-queries.css"... />

Answer (score 0):

This will probably be more involved than you want but let's start with [CSS3 Media Query spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/).

A couple things that shouldn't be problematic but I will address:
1. You only need the html5shim from google if you want older versions of IE to recognize new HTML5 elements--which technically shouldn't be in XHTML
2. Your linked "media-queries.css" stylesheet is missing a self-closing bracket '/>'

From what I have read, those little inconsistencies don't cause browsers many problems but if your code starts doing funny stuff you should always double check for inaccuracies.

I don't see anything below the head but I assume you just meant towards the bottom of what is pasted. That said, what you pasted should be functional (X)HTML but there are no actual CSS media queries included.

This is a responsive CSS3 @Media Query stylesheet to a repo on Github (a Twitter Bootstrap based WordPress Theme) https://github.com/retlehs/roots/blob/master/assets/css/bootstrap-responsive.css

Between those docs and the actual Twitter Bootstrap (also on Github, the CSS is identical) docs you should be able to see how others are doing it and why.

Hope it helps but without a look at the actual CSS there is no way for me to guess why it isn't working.

Comment: Hi Adam... can you pop into the Javascript chat? Im in there... basically i had a look at for me to import into WP its using the above function? (some of the above terminology is blagging my head) basically its an external CSS from a DEMO on responsive site design i found

Comment: I don't usually linger on here (it's too easy to read about topics other than whatever I am currently working on). I'd be willing to help you make sense of some stuff (if I can, I am still pretty new and often need things explained too). My email is on my profile, if you want to meet in a chat room or whatever just get in touch with me first so we can plan a time.